# How to test api requests and fill classes with fake data?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit

I can not find a solution to this problem on the Internet. Or is my code so bad?

Interface

```
interface GetWeatherService {
    @GET("/data/2.5/forecast?")
    fun getAllWeather(@Query("q")cityName: String, @Query("APPID")app_id: String, @Query("units")units: String="imperial"): Call<ListWeather>

    @GET("/data/2.5/weather?")
    fun getCurrentWeather(@Query("q")cityName: String, @Query("APPID")app_id: String, @Query("units")units: String="imperial"): Call<MainWeather>

    @GET("/data/2.5/weather?")
    fun getWeatherDataFromLocation(@Query("lat")lat: String, @Query("lon")lon: String, @Query("APPID") app_id: String): Call<DataFromLocation>

}
```

Client

```
object RetrofitClientInstance {
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    private var BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/"

    val retrofitInstance: Retrofit?
        get(){
            if(retrofit == null){
                retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit
        }
}
```

MainActivity()

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity {
  fun getDataFromApi(cityName: String) {

        val service = RetrofitClientInstance.retrofitInstance!!.create(GetWeatherService::class.java)

        // Service 1

        service.getCurrentWeather(cityName, APP_ID).enqueue(object: Callback<MainWeather>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MainWeather>, t: Throwable) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MainWeather>, response: Response<MainWeather>) {
                val weather = response.body()
                val currentWeather = CurrentWeather(
                    weather!!.main.temp,
                    weather.weather[0].description,
                    weather.name,
                    weather.weather[0].main
                )
                updateCurrentWeatherUI(currentWeather)
            }
        })

        service.getAllWeather(cityName, APP_ID).enqueue(object: Callback<ListWeather>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ListWeather>, t: Throwable) {
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ListWeather>, response: Response<ListWeather>) {
                val weather = response.body()!!.list

                for(item in weather){
                    val weatherList = NextFiveDayWeather(
                        item.dt,
                        item.main.temp,
                        item.weather[0].description
                    )
                    weatherArray.add(weatherList)
                    updateUI(weatherArray)

                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Data class

```
data class MainWeather (
    var dt: Long,
    var main: MainDTO,
    var weather: List<WeatherDTO>,
    var dt_txt: String,
    var name: String
)

data class WeatherDTO (var main: String, var description: String, var icon: String)

data class ListWeather (@SerializedName("list") var list: List<MainWeather>)
```

I can’t test the request to api and I can’t fill the classes with fake data?
Tell me please, what should I do?
What should I study? And if you are not difficult can give advice for the future?

Comment: With mockito you can mock network call

Comment: Write tests or , You can use some online sites to get static json data ex: https://jsonblob.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the software Postman to test api endpoints: https://www.getpostman.com/